# libgnomeui-0 dependency problem 17.10

Tags: 17.10, dependencies

This issue is driving me nuts, anytime I try to do any install, uninstall, upgrade or update I run into this error:

```
libgnomeui-0 : Depends: libgnomeui-common (= 2.24.5-3.1) but 2.24.5-3.2 is to be installed
```

I have tried a number of various things to fix it but nothing seems to work, any new ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Give the result of `apt update; apt install -f`

Comment: `Preparing to unpack .../libgnomeui-0_2.24.5-3.2_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgnomeui-0_2.24.5-3.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive syntax
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgnomeui-0_2.24.5-3.2_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to let `apt` fix this issue? What I mean by this is simply running:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

#### Alternative solution

Have you tried manually installing each of these missing dependencies??? To get a list you can run something like:

```
apt-cache depends libgnomeui-0
```

And then you could manually try installing each one, with:

```
sudo apt install dependency_here
```

#### Last Option

Have you tried just deleting `libgnomeui-0`?

Comment: Yes then I end up getting:

`dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgnomeui-0_2.24.5-3.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive syntax`

Comment: I do appreciate the help. I have tried all those things. It seems the problem is `libgnomeui-0` depends on `libgnomeui-common` version `2.24.5-3.1` but that version does not exist.

How do I just delete `libgnomeui-0`? If I try to uninstall it, I get the same dependency problem preventing the uninstall.

Comment: Try running `apt remove --purge libgnomeui-0 && apt autoremove`

Comment: That results in `dpkg: error processing package libgnomeui-0:amd64 (--remove):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive syntax
`

Comment: Have you tried removing the trigger by running `sudo -s
echo "#Nothing to do here" > /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.triggers
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get dist-upgrade` -->

Comment: Same thing...sorry